# How to store user actions when page is refreshed

Tags: angular, typescript

When the app loads, `this.initialValue` will be false.

I have a toggle button, which returns `boolean` based on user action.

Based on the user action `this.initialValue` will change to `true` or `false`.

I need to save the last user action, even when the user reloads the page.

I can use the `localSotage` to save the event value. But I need to destroy the event when a user closes the application.

Please suggest me some ideas on how to achieve this?.

```
constructor(){ this.initialValue = false}

onToggle(event) {
  if(event === true){
    this.initialValue = true
    } else if (event === false) {
    this.initialValue = false
   }
}
```

Comment: You can also look for `sessionStorage`. Storage will be deleted when page is closed

Comment: will it work, if i open the app in different tab ?

Comment: I think, No. You can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: How does the user “close the application”?  Do they logout?  Or do you mean close the browser?

Comment: Session storage lasts as long as the browser is open (at least in Chrome, I haven't tried Firebox/Edge/Opera/Safari).  If you open another tab, close the first, and re-navigate to the Angular app, the storage is still available.  It is cleared when the clear() method is called, or when the browser is closed.